# Ant task to pick words from a String

Tags: ant

Say I have the string - "D:\ApEx_Schema\Functions\new.sql@@\main\ONEVIEW_Integration\3"
I require to fetch the following into diff variables
- file name
 - file path 
 - and the version (which is the last character of the string)

Pls any helps using ANT tasks

======================================
I am trying to read a txt file which contains data as given below :-

```
.\ApEx_Schema\Functions\new.sql@@\main\ONEVIEW_Integration\3

.\ApEx_Schema\Functions\Functions.sql@@\main\ONEVIEW_Integration\3

.\ApEx_Schema\Indexes\Indexes.sql@@\main\ONEVIEW_Integration\2
```

and trying to collect the file name, its path details and its version and updating the same in a DB using the SQL task.
Though my build.xml is not giving output as desired.
Any suggestions and views!!!

My Build.xml file looks like -
==============START===========================

```
<description>
    obiee copy files build file
</description>
```

```
<replace file="D:\buildFRIDAY\database.txt" token=".\" value="D:\"/>  
<loadfile property="src" srcFile="D:\buildFRIDAY\database.txt"/> 

<path id="antclasspath"> 
    <fileset dir="D:\OraHome_1\oracledi\drivers">     
    <include name="ojdbc14.jar"/>    
    </fileset>  
</path>  

<for list="${src}" param="detls" delimiter="${line.separator}"> 
 <sequential>   
        <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
        <propertyregex property="path" input="@{detls}"
                       regexp="(.*)\\.*@@" select="\1" />
        <propertyregex property="file" input="@{detls}"
                       regexp=".*\\(.*)@@" select="\1" />
        <propertyregex property="version" input="@{detls}"
                       regexp=".*\\(.*)" select="\1" />

        <echo>
        Input:   @{detls}
        Path:    ${path}
        File:    ${file}
        Version: ${version}
        </echo>

        <if>
                <matches string="@{detls}" pattern=".sql"  /> 
         <then>

         </then>
        </if>

        <if>
                <matches string="@{detls}" pattern="[0-9]"  /> 
     <then>
            <sql     
                driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"   
                url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.88.68:1521:rdev"   
                userid="rapid"    
                password="rapid"     
                print="yes"     
                classpathref="antclasspath">     

                Insert into ROLTA_PATCH_FILE_APP_TAB (PATCH_NO,FILE_NAME,FILE_PATH,FILE_VERSION,APPLIED_DATE,STATUS) values ('3.2.12',"@{detls}",'D:\ApEx_Schema\Functions\Functions.sql','3',to_date('11-MAR-11','DD-MON-RR'),'Y');

                Insert into ROLTA_PATCH_TAB (PATCH_NO,PATCH_NAME,APPL_NAME,APPLIED_DATE) values ('3.2.12','2.1.11','@{detls}',to_date('11-MAR-11','DD-MON-RR'));
            </sql>  
         </then>
        </if>
  </sequential> 
</for>
```

==============END===========================

Answer (score 2):

This isn't something that Ant is good at.
Probably the simplest solution is to use the [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) [`propertyregex` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html):

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>

<property name="candidate"
          value="D:\ApEx_Schema\Functions\new.sql@@\main\ONEVIEW_Integration\3" />

<propertyregex property="path" input="${candidate}"
               regexp="(.*)\\.*@@" select="\1" />
<propertyregex property="file" input="${candidate}"
               regexp=".*\\(.*)@@" select="\1" />
<propertyregex property="version" input="${candidate}"
               regexp=".*\\(.*)" select="\1" />

<echo>
Input:   ${candidate}
Path:    ${path}
File:    ${file}
Version: ${version}
</echo>
```

That involves getting hold of the jar of the ant-contrib collection of tasks.

A - pretty nasty - alternative is to use a [`scriptdef` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html).

```
<scriptdef name="get_elements" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="candidate" />
    <attribute name="path-property" />
    <attribute name="file-property" />
    <attribute name="version-property" />
    <![CDATA[
        filesep = project.getProperty( "file.separator" );
        candidate = attributes.get( "candidate" );
        path = candidate.substring( 0, candidate.indexOf( "@@" ) );
        file = path.substring( path.lastIndexOf( filesep ) + 1 );
        path = path.substring( 0, path.lastIndexOf( filesep ) );
        version = candidate.substring( candidate.lastIndexOf( filesep )  + 1 );

        project.setProperty( attributes.get( "path-property" ), path );
        project.setProperty( attributes.get( "file-property" ), file );
        project.setProperty( attributes.get( "version-property" ), version );
    ]]>
</scriptdef>

<property name="candidate"
          location="D:\ApEx_Schema\Functions\new.sql@@\main\ONEVIEW_Integration\3"
          relative="yes" />
<get_elements candidate="${candidate}"
              path-property="path"
              file-property="file"
              version-property="version" />
<echo>
Input:   ${candidate}
Path:    ${path}
File:    ${file}
Version: ${version}
</echo>
```

(Note: tested this on a unix OS, so you may need to adjust path separator treatments if on Windows.)

**Update:**

Some notes on your implementation.

You may need to namespace the 'for' task:

```
<ac:for list="${src}" param="detls" delimiter="${line.separator}"
        xmlns:ac="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib">
    ...
</ac:for>
```

If you want `propertyregex` to change a property (which you do as you're iterating) you need to set
   `override="yes"` on each of those.
Inside a `for` you need to escape the at signs, for example:

```
<propertyregex property="path"
               input="@{detls}"
               regexp="(.*)\\.*\@\@" select="\1"
               override="yes"/>
```

To refer to the property set by the `propertyregex` use `${path}` rather than `@{path}`.

Comment: Martin it worked for single string, can u pls suggest help for multiple strings in a file ... Thanks

Comment: Thanks Martin... will check out your code and let you know..thanks

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that won't require the contributed task "propertyregex", nor javascript.

```xml
<property name="candidate" value="D:\ApEx_Schema\Functions\new.sql@@\main\ONEVIEW_Integration\3" />

<pathconvert property="path">
    <path location="${candidate}" />
    <regexpmapper from="(.*)\\.*@@" to="\1" />
</pathconvert>

<pathconvert property="file">
    <path location="${candidate}" />
    <regexpmapper from=".*\\(.*)@@" to="\1" />
</pathconvert>

<pathconvert property="version">
    <path location="${candidate}" />
    <regexpmapper from=".*\\(.*)" to="\1" />
</pathconvert>

<echo>
Input:   ${candidate}
Path:    ${path}
File:    ${file}
Version: ${version}
</echo>
```